# Combine Lines in only one line with delimiter

Tags: notepad++

> phr0ke
>   batista
>   233633
>   2j59toye

i need a regex for this format

> phr0ke:batista
>   233633:2j59toye

i try with /r/n but all results in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

**Step 1:**

Using extended mode replace `\r\n` to `:`
You will get something like:

> phr0ke:batista:233633:2j59toye:

*If there is no semicolon in the end of line - add it*

**Step 2:**

Place the cursor in the beginning of the file.
Using regexp mode replace `([^:]*):([^:]*):` with `(\1):(\2)\n`.
It will replace every `a:b:` sentences to `a:b\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one step:

- Click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\R(.+)`
- Replace with: `$1:$2`
- Click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked but NOT `dot matches newline`.

`\R` stands for any kind of newline (`\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`)